# Sound effects with windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I'd like to try creating some sound effects with the windows phone 7.  I found a sample from microsoft that shows how to get the input from the microphone.

[Microphone Input Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442302%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

I don't know anything about sound manipulation through code - are there any example for changing the pitch, tone, etc of the microphone input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx). It has the ability to [alter pitch and pan when playing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904205.aspx) a sound.

You could also try experimenting with the [DopplerScale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.dopplerscale.aspx) and [DistanceScale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.distancescale.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start.  Is there anything  you know of that can do distortions - reverb, echoes, etc?